# Probability question: choosing between two options

Tags: probability, statistics

I am having trouble understanding the following exercise in probability and statistics:

A person has to choose between two jobs. In Job1, they have a profit of 12k with a 75% probability, while they have a damage of 3k with probability 25%. In Job2, they have a profit of 18k with probability 50%, while they have a damage of 4.5k with probability 50%. If the person needs to earn at least 15k, which job should they choose?

I cannot understand what I have to do here. This is an exercise in a revision, so anything is on the table. I am really confused by this, since I don't even know if any random variable follows some distribution. Could you please help me out?

Comment: I guess you have to compare *average* profit for each job.

Comment: @Miguel But how? simply take the average of $(12*0.75-3*0.25)/2$ and compare it to $(18*0.5-4.5*0.5)/2$? this seems kind of "too simple", i don't know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course he has to chose Job2, independently about any profit expectation.

This because he has as a goal to get AT LEAST 15k but the job1 has a maximun profit of only 12k

In other words, choosing Job2 he has 50% probability to get goal, choosing Job1 he has 0% probability to get goal

Comment: That was my first thought too, but it seems way too easy so I rejected it

Comment: I am not sure what the author means by those probabilities. Maybe they mean "have a profit of at least.." and "have a damage of at least.." instead of exact?

Answer (score 1):

With Job1, the person has zero probability of earning 15K whereas with job2, there is 50% chance that he/she can earn that. Should it not be that simple unless I am missing something?